# Do we really need edit summaries?

Tags: discussion, edits

I've asked myself this question many times when editing or (re)viewing edits but I fail to see why. IMO the GUI is doing quite a good job at highlighting the changes. And to be honest, I rarely look at the summaries. It might be just me but I always compare the previous revision to the proposed/current revision.

Comment: I use them all the time, both in terms of understanding someone else's edit history and when doing the editing oneself (for others to read).

Comment: I think downvotes are people saying *"Yes, we need summaries and your question is out of place"*, but double ++ for bringing up the topic.

Comment: *Do we really need commit messages?*

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I see (now) why it's useful in those cases listed in Servy's answer. And for all I know it could just be a coincidence that almost all edit summaries I see (Q&As tagged with my favorite tag - not plural) are self-explainable. I guess, in time, when/if I start to widen the way I use SO I might find those summaries more use-/helpful.

Comment: The diff tells *what*. The summary tells *why*. Completely different things. The why is only optional when it is truly self-evident.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, they are useful.  Maybe not every single time, but often enough that they need to be there.

The revision notes shouldn't be used to describe *what* you're changing, but rather *why* you are making the change.

Now in many cases this is obvious.  You don't (usually) need to explain *why* you're fixing the spelling of a word, for example, but sometimes the reason for a given change *isn't* obvious.  For example, sometimes an edit is incorporating information the author posted in a comment into the post.  That's important to call out in the revision notes, else it looks like a radical change by someone other than the author.  Another might be removing an answer that is edited into the question.  You can explain that the answer belongs in an answer to the question when editing it out.  Conflicting edits, made around the same time, can also sometimes cause big messes; having revision notes to, for example, indicate that a given change is merging several conflicting edits can help make sense of what might otherwise look like an inappropriate edit.

Now if including a revision note were optional, that's something I could get behind.  It'd actually *help* in that rather than seeing the revision note filled with filler text such as "X characters edited" 90% of the time, the revision note would only be there at all when the editor had something important to say, making it stand out that much more when they *do* take the time to draw attention to something.

Comment: The `optional` part is interesting because it would give the summary more value. Instead of seeing `Removed tag from title`, `Removed invalid tag` etc.

Comment: especially for suggested edits (that have to be approved) a summary like "bringing in content from the comments" can make the difference between being approved and being rejected as a radical change.

Answer (score 2):

I'll exemplify [Servy's *why*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270771/do-we-really-need-edit-summaries/270772#270772) regarding edits in general, not only on the Review Queue.

New unnamed user12345 asks:

> Title: Problem with X
> [...*question content*...]
> Thanks in advanced,
> User Name/Nick

I'll edit the title to "X produces Y when I try Z", fix some stuff on the content and the edit summary will be:

> Descriptive title. Thank people by upvoting useful answers. Signatures are forbidden (fill your profile to show your name in the user box bellow the post).

If it's not a new user, simply this:

> Descriptive title. See `http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts`

If the user, new or old, has some interest on how things work, s/he'll see the message. If not, at some moment it will be useful to some other interested user.

<sup>That's just one example, but the goal is to teach other users how to edit/format a question/answer.</sup>

In case of answers, there's other aspect. We're not editing someone's post who's *asking* for free help, we're editing someone's who's *offering* free help, and IMO it's a sign of respect to explain why you're editing their post. Unless the fix is plain obvious, I'll leave at least a minimal explanation why the edit was justified.

Summarizing: it's an optional field but it can it can contain useful information for the poster him/herself and to the editorial flow of a post.

Comment: "Thank people by upvoting useful answers" doesn't belong in an edit summary.  It has nothing to do with an edit.  It would belong in a comment... except that new users can't upvote anyways so it's just noise.